# Get self in dynamically loaded component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I followed https://medium.com/@rmmmsy/creating-a-sidebar-with-dynamic-content-using-vue-and-vuex-88e904894e00 to create a vuex-based sidebar-toggle.

Well - I would like to implement a "close"-button within my sidebar. Actually I can not access `this.component` inside this sidebar-component.

So at the moment I am doing this as a dirty workaround:

This is my layout file:

```
<template>
    <div class="min-h-screen">
        <div>
            <header>
                <Navbar/>
            </header>
            <main>
                <SlideOvers />
                <router-view/>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <div id="footer">
                    <div>
                        <Footerbar/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Footerbar from '../components/Navigation/Footerbar/Footerbar';
import Navbar from '../components/Navigation/Navbar/Navbar';
import SlideOvers from "./SlideOvers";

export default {
    name: 'Layout-1',
    components: {SlideOvers, Footerbar, Navbar},
    },
};
</script>
```

This is the `SliveOvers`-component:

```
<template>
    <component :is="component" :component="component" v-if="open"/>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: 'SlideOvers',
    components: {},
    watch: {
        '$route' () {
            this.$store.dispatch ('closeSidebar', this.component)
        },
    },
    computed: {
        open () {
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarOpen
        },
        component () {
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

This is one button that triggers the slideover:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="handleClick"
                class="btn">
         Open user menu
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import UserSlideover from "../../Slideovers/User/UserSlideover";

export default {
    name: "UserMenuButton",
    data () {
        return {
            component: UserSlideover,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        computedOpen () {
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarOpen && this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent === this.component
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick () {
            this.$store.dispatch ('toggleSidebar', this.component)
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

In the sidebar:

```
props: {
        component: {
            type: Object
        },
    },
    computed: {
        computedOpen () {
            console.log (this.component);
            return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarOpen && this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent === this.component
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick () {
            this.$store.dispatch ('toggleSidebar', this.component)
        }
    }
```

I think this is not the best solution I ever came up with.

Does anybody has a better idea here?

Comment: I am a bit confused. The `:is="component` line showing that the component is the component being rendered? Please could you post the full layout file so you can receive better help.

Comment: Please could you tell me where the `sidebar` component comes in? I can't see it in the code. Is it a part of the `slideovers` component? Why do you need to dispatch the component to the store? Could you show the Vuex store, please?

Comment: The sidebar-component is in this case, the `UserSlideover` component.

Comment: In addition to my answer, It seems like you are `this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent` as props to the component. Why can't you use `this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent` throughout the application since the store state is global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your solution, really. However, if you are looking for an alternative to passing `component` as props, you can make the computed property, `component`, global

#### main.vue

```js
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    data: {
        ...
    },
    computed: {
      component() {
        return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent
      }
    },
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

You can now access it in your components using `this.$root`

#### sidebar.vue

```js
computed: {
  computedOpen () {
      console.log (this.component);
      return this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarOpen && this.$store.state.slideovers.sidebarComponent === this.$root.component // use this.$root.component to access the computed property in the root instance
  }
},
methods: {
    handleClick () {
        this.$store.dispatch ('toggleSidebar', this.$root.component)
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is not the most elegant solution. You can decide which method you prefer.